# RadDateTimePicker change to time only client side

Tags: telerik

So I have this DateTimePicker on my page

```
< telerik:raddatetimepicker id="StartDateTimePicker" runat="server">
    < Calendar ID="StartCalendar" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="true" />
    < DateInput ID="DateInput1" ToolTip="Date input" runat="server" />
< /telerik:raddatetimepicker>
```

All is working fine, but now I need to be able to toggle this to display only time when a client side event happens.  I'd like to still get the date/time result from the server side but on client side I only want to show as a date picker.

I did try setting the DisplayDateFormat on the DateInput to "h:mm tt" at design time and I only saw time being shown in the text box, but I need to be able to toggle this on and off so this will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have this figured out.  I found that I can call

```
var picker = $find("<%= StartDateTimePicker.ClientID %>");
picker.get_popupButton().style.display = "none";
```

to hide the calendar button and then can call

```
var format = picker.get_dateInput();
format.set_displayDateFormat('h:mm tt');
```

to change the display format to only show time.  Then just need to call

```
format.set_value(format.get_value());
```

to have the text in the text box get updated to the new format.

All can be toggled back by calling

```
var picker = $find("<%= StartDateTimePicker.ClientID %>");
picker.get_popupButton().style.display = "";

var format = picker.get_dateInput();
format.set_displayDateFormat('M/d/yyyy h:mm tt');
format.set_value(format.get_value());
```